# Binary Search Tree Delete two Child

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete a node from a Binary Search Tree with two children. Everything works as I wrote it, but after deleting `min` I run into problems when trying to print the Tree. Is there anything wrong with my algorithm?

```
void BST::DeleteTwoChild(Node * Current, Node * Parent)
{
    // Declare min
    Node * min = Current;
    Node * minParent = NULL;
    // Loop until minimum value is found
    while (min->Right != nullptr)
    {
        minParent = min;
        min = min->Right;
    }
    while (min->Left != nullptr)
    {
                minParent = min;
                min = min->Left;
    }

    // Copy contents of min to Current (Node info being deleted)
    Current->Data = min->Data;
    Current->Frequency = min->Frequency;

    // Delete the duplicate (min)
    delete min;
}
```

EDIT:
Solution was to add `minParent->Left = nullptr;` before `delete`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete min if any other node still points to it. Usually you would set that pointer to NULL first.

Comment: That fixed my problems. Thanks

Comment: @Darkstorm51 Welcome to StackOverflow -- if this is the correct answer, please click the checkmark on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure because you didn't provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but try to add

```
minParent->Left = nullptr;
```

before `delete` operator.